# SML: How to take the tl of a list x number of times?

Tags: sml, smlnj

I'm working on an assignment, and the problem I'm running into is that I am unsure how to take the `tl` of a list `x` number of times within a function. `x` is given when the function is ran, but anytime before then I don't know.

Comment: Lists are immutable (they can't be modified), so the `tl` of a list will never change no matter how many times you take it . . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is already a built-in function for this: `List.drop (xs, n)` drops `n` elements from `xs`. Since "taking the tail" is equivalent to dropping one element, dropping `n` elements is equivalent to "taking the tail" `n` times.

```
- List.drop ([1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21], 5);
> val it = [8, 13, 21] : int list
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it. I had to write a Helper function that took the `tl` of my list however many times I needed it to.

Thanks!

Comment: this should be a comment.